# Create a realistic puddle?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, photorealism

I'm creating a scene involving a spilled Nuka-Cola bottle. Here's how it looks:[image]

The puddle on the ground looks too.. smooth. I would like it too look a little bit more noisy and realistic. Changing color settings or roughness or IOR didn't help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It should have some roughness (probably 0.025-0.1), IOR much more around 1 (4.9 is ridiculously high), could also use some glossy shader mixed in...

Comment: https://youtu.be/oojlF0m8KSE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your Blender file, i've done the following node setup, if you do the same, just change a bit your camera position or lightsource position, so the fluid can have something to reflect:[image: NukaCola]

Answer (score 0):

On node editor, you can try the following:
add glass shader -->
add glossy shader-->
add mix shader-->
add layer weight-->
connect glass and glossy to "shader" in mix shader node-->
connect layer weight node's "facing" or "fresnel" to "fac" in mix shader-->
connect mix shader to material output.
Instead of using glass shader, you can also consider using transparent shader

Comment: as your IOR might be too high, you might consider to use some more realistic values, like on the following post:
http://forums.cgsociety.org/archive/index.php?t-513458.html

Comment: please use the **edit** link at the bottom of your answer to add or correct information on your original question.